Firebase not automatically authenticating to invoke cloud functions
Cloud Function (Gen 2) (When I allow unauthenticated invocations, the function is called properly, and results are proper as well. However, issues occur when I configure the function to require authentication.)
import functions_framework
from google.auth import default
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from flask import jsonify


@functions_framework.http
def verify_purchase_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function to verify Android subscription purchases."""
    try:
        # Use Application Default Credentials (ADC)
        credentials, project = default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])
        androidpublisher = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to initialize credentials or service: ", str(e))
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to initialize credentials or service"}), 500

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    if request_json:
        # Extract the token depending on the structure
        if 'data' in request_json:
            purchase_token = request_json['data'].get('token')
        else:
            purchase_token = request_json.get('token')
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid request format"}), 400

    package_name = "" #Already added
    subscription_id = "premium"

    if not purchase_token:
        print("no token found")
        return jsonify({"error": "Token is required"}), 400

    try:
        subscription = androidpublisher.purchases().subscriptions().get(
            packageName=package_name,
            subscriptionId=subscription_id,
            token=purchase_token
        ).execute()

        return jsonify({"data": subscription}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error calling Google Play API: ", str(e))
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500


Calling the function (Android Kotlin)
private fun testVerifyPurchase() {
        // Hardcoded test purchase token
        val testPurchaseToken = "" #Added test purchase token

        Log.d("PremiumFragment", "Testing verify purchase with token: $testPurchaseToken")

        // Call Firebase function
        verifyPurchaseWithFirebase(testPurchaseToken)
    }

    private fun verifyPurchaseWithFirebase(purchaseToken: String) {

        // Get the currently signed-in user
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        user?.getIdToken(true)?.addOnCompleteListener { idTokenTask ->
            if (idTokenTask.isSuccessful) {
                val idToken = idTokenTask.result?.token
                Log.d("PremiumFragment", "ID Token: $idToken")

                // Ensure the ID token is not null
                if (idToken != null) {
                    val data = hashMapOf(
                        "token" to purchaseToken
                    )

                    Log.d("PremiumFragment", "Verifying purchase with token: $purchaseToken")
                    Log.d("PremiumFragment", "Data to send to Firebase: $data")

                    functions
                        .getHttpsCallable("verify_purchase")
                        .call(data)
                        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                Log.d(
                                    "PremiumFragment",
                                    "Purchase verified successfully with Firebase"
                                )
                                val result = task.result?.data as? Map<String, Any>
                                if (result != null) {
                                    Log.d("PremiumFragment", "Result from Firebase: $result")
                                    // Update the UI or take necessary actions based on the result
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(
                                        "PremiumFragment",
                                        "No data received from Firebase function"
                                    )
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d("PremiumFragment", task.result.toString())
                                Log.e(
                                    "PremiumFragment",
                                    "Failed to verify purchase with Firebase",
                                    task.exception
                                )
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

ERROR

com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: UNAUTHENTICATED

I don't understand though, how am I supposed to go about this? I've checked documentation on the matter and it seems that authentication should automatically be handled if I'm using firebase.

With callables, Firebase Authentication tokens, FCM tokens, and App Check tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests.
The trigger automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens.

I've added cloud run invoker roles to the default compute service account which is the build service account.
Can someone please explain why this isn't automatically authenticated? Moreover, if there isn't a fix for this, can somebody please suggest an alternative to this? I am new to function deployment and android development in general, so I am probably misunderstanding something, please bear with me, thank you!

You didn't write a callable function - you wrote a normal HTTP function instead.  I suggest reviewing the linked documentation to better understand the difference between how they are written.  If you want a callable, you will annotate the function with @https_fn.on_call instead of @https_fn.on_request (among other differences).
Also I suggest checking the functions logs to understand when things might have gone wrong with the function.  You won't see all the errors and diagnostics in the exceptions you catch in your app.
